# Is it possible to access GraphicsDeviceManager from my GameObject class?

Tags: c#, xna

Alright, so I am a beginner in this.

I have a GameObject class, and I want this class to have access to the graphics device, so I'll be able to get the Max Screen width for example.
My target is to use the MaxScreen width when I create other objects that inherit from GameObject class, maybe there should be another easier way to do this thing, but yeah.

If anyone haven't understood anything, I'll be glad to explain more.
Thanks alot.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate question. Check my answer from your latest question.

Comment: This really isn't an XNA specific question, it has more to do with code design imo... I think you should look at some game samples provided by Microsoft (see here: http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/?contenttype=4&devarea=5&platform=0&sort=1) as a good starting point as they are generally well written (the platformer sample as well as the capault sample are two good examples).

Answer (score -1):

To get access to the GraphicsDevice you need to subclass the XNA class "Game".  Once you've done that you can access the GraphicsDevice properties and if you really want to share it with other objects in your version of the "Game" class.  I reccomend you complete the "Getting Started" section on MSDN and read the introduction.  Links are below

XNA Getting Started [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203893%28v=XNAGameStudio.31%29.aspx)

Introduction to the XNA framework [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203893%28v=XNAGameStudio.31%29.aspx)